# EntityFrameworkCore: How to save an entity with ForeignKey to another model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a model that relates to another:

```
public class Portfolio : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Org Organization { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to save it (pointing the value of the `organization` field to an existing record in the database), the ModelState is not valid ("Organization": The input was not valid).

I send the `id` of the `Organization` with the rest of the payload:

```
{
    "Name": "Port 1",
    "Organization": 16
}
```

and the Controller code is very simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Portfolio item){
     if (ModelState.IsValid){
         _PortfolioRepo.Add(item);
         _PortfolioRepo.Commit();
         return new OkObjectResult(item);
         }
     else{
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }
}
```

The interesting part is that when I specify the `Organization` field in the payload, the `item` in the `Create()` method will come as `null` so I can't manually retrieve the `Organization` from its repo and link to `Portfolio` either. When I omit the `Organization`, it will save the entity just fine.

If I enclose the details of the `Organization` inside the payload, then the EF will save a *new* Organization record in the database. But how do I link to existing one vs saving a new model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Portfolio` model you have this property:

```
public Org Organization { get; set; }
```

Please note the type of the property is `Org`. So setting it to a number will not work for obvious reasons. Try changing your model a little to something like this:

```
public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
public Org Organization { get; set; }
```

That will tell EF that the `Organization` property is a navigation property and the foreign key for it is `OrganizationId`. Set the `OrganizationId` property and it should work.

Comment: You should also add "virtual" key work for Org property to enable Lazy-Loading and to get more efficient change tracking

Comment: @Hassan Lazy Loading doesn't presently exist in EFC